# Libgdx sound plays after delay in Android

Tags: android, audio, libgdx, delay

I'm building a game in Libgdx (Android) where I play a sound every time the user touches on some object. The sound and the visual selection of the object should be coordinated, but when I play the sound there's a 200ms latency since I call sound.play() and the moment the sound starts actually playing.

I am using an AssetManager to load all the sound files before the game starts, and I have confirmed that the time delay is between the sound.play() call and when sound.getPosition() stops being 0. So my question is, what is happening here? What are Libgdx or Android doing between those 2 moments that takes 200 ms, given that the file is already loaded? This is a .wav file, so not very much compressed at all. Is there something I'm missing or some way to fix it?

Comment: Do you use `Music` instance for playing the sound? If it's a small file, less than 1Mb, try using `Sound`. It will load the sound into RAM, instead of streaming it from disk. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Sound-effects

Comment: Iirc, Android has some extra prep work to do the first time it plays a sound. Workaround is to cycle through all sounds when loading is complete and play them at zero volume to prime them for faster subsequent playback.

Answer (score 0):

In libGDX 1.9.12 you can use `AsynchronousAndroidAudio` which may help you to solve the issue.

You can change default LibGDX behavior and use `AsynchronousAndroidAudio` by overriding this method in your `AndroidLauncher` class:

```
@Override
public AndroidAudio createAudio(Context context, AndroidApplicationConfiguration config) {
    return new AsynchronousAndroidAudio(context, config);
}
```

There is one limitation: no option to use sound id.

See the [official documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Audio) for more info and also [the pull request](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/6243)

Also, if for any reasons you need sound id you can take this implementation as an example and find a workaround for your project.